# Type of a function that applies a decorator to every function in a module

Tags: typescript

I have a function decorator, for example:

```js
// Just to have an example of a decorator that changes the type
type Foo<T> = T;
type Bar<T> = T;

function someDecorator<T, U extends unknown[]>(fn: (...args: U) => Foo<T>) : (...args: U) => Bar<T> {
  return fn;
}
```

And I want to apply that decorator to every function in a module:

```js
export function decorateModule(m : any) {
  let newModule = {} as any;
  Object.keys(m).forEach(function(k) {
    newModule[k] = someDecorator(m[k]);
  });
  return newModule;
}
```

What is the type of decorateModule (without `any`)?

Comment: `function decorateModule<T>(m : T): T`, of course.

Comment: are you sure you wanna `return m`? not `return newModule`?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to return newModule. (m : T) : T doesn't work, what is the type of newModule?

Comment: I tried some stuff, but don't know if it is closer to what you need. It seems to have some issues, though (notice the `NOOO` on line 16, it shouldn't work, should it?) TS Playground link: bit.ly/2ZQVsQR

Comment: That doesn't preserve the keys of the module, ie you can do newModule.anything() which would be a runtime error. I think it also enforces that all the functions in the module have the same type

Comment: @GavinWahl Ah I see. It can be done by combining `Parameters` and `ReturnType`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function decorateModule<T>(m: T): { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ?
        (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => ReturnType<T[K]> extends Foo<infer Z> ? Bar<Z> : never
    : never
} {
    let newModule = {} as any;
    Object.keys(m).forEach(function (k) {
        newModule[k] = someDecorator(m[k]);
    });
    return newModule;
}
```

I know this is not very readable, but it works. Check the [TS playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Foo%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Bar%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20someDecorator%3CT%2C%20U%20extends%20unknown%5B%5D%3E(fn%3A%20(...args%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20Foo%3CT%3E)%20%3A%20(...args%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20Bar%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20fn%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20decorateModule%3CT%3E(m%3A%20T)%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(...args%3A%20Parameters%3CT%5BK%5D%3E)%20%3D%3E%20ReturnType%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20extends%20Foo%3Cinfer%20Z%3E%20%3F%20Bar%3CZ%3E%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20newModule%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.keys(m).forEach(function%20(k)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20newModule%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20someDecorator(m%5Bk%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20newModule%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myModule%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foobar(n%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20foo%3A%20true%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newModule%20%3D%20decorateModule(myModule)).

Comment: Still not type safe with the 'as any'

Comment: @GavinWahl I'm no perfectionist, just being practical. give me a case you see as unsafe to prove your point.